# Expo app aws-exports.js in production redirect url's?

Tags: expo, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

```
oauth: {
    domain: 'powrapp04889517-04889517-dev.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com',
    scope: [
      'phone',
      'email',
      'openid',
      'profile',
      'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin',
    ],
    redirectSignIn: 'exp://10.42.0.89:19000/--/',
    redirectSignOut: 'exp://10.42.0.89:19000/--/',
    responseType: 'code',
  },
```

as you can see I am using my local IP to test the app from Expo, which redirectSignIn, redirectSignOut urls are used when the app is ready for publishing? Is it possible to use multiple urls?